# When does (MKAnnotationView)mapView actually get called?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm making an app that uses this method, and I thought that this method was supposed to be called every time the `addAnnotation` method is called?  Because that doesn't seem to be the case for my app.

In the code below, the method `updateNodes` is called regularly. In this method, the `addAnnotation` method is called.  So theoretically, so should be the `mapView` method, right?

However, I put in an NSLog statement, but it is never printed.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    NSLog(@"Map View Method Called");
        if(!currentParty.alreadyAdded){
            MKAnnotationView *pinView = [self returnPointView:[currentParty getPartylocation] andTitle:[currentParty getPartyName]
                                                     andColor:[currentParty getPartyColor]];
            NSLog(@"Adding Successful!");
            currentParty.annot = pinView.annotation;
            currentParty.alreadyAdded = YES;
            return pinView;
        }
    return NULL;
}

-(void) updateNodes{
    NSLog(@"Update Nodes Method Call");
    for(Party *party in allParties){
        if(!party.alreadyAdded){
            party.alreadyAdded = YES;
            currentParty = party;
            [self.map addAnnotation:currentParty.annot];
            NSLog(@"Adding Successful!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do the annotations at least appear as red pins?  If self.map is an IBOutlet, make sure it is connected to the MKMapView in the xib.  Is the map view's delegate set/connected?  Does the addAnnotation line actually execute and is currentParty.annot actually set (ie. not nil) when it is called?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's getting called or not, the implementation of viewForAnnotation does not look right.  If an annotation was "already added", you can't return NULL since then it will show the default red pin instead of your custom view.

Comment: Also (this is critical): you should not rely on the external variable currentParty for the logic inside the viewForAnnotation delegate method.  The delegate method is not necessarily called once or immediately after addAnnotation.  It may be called a little later or again for the same already-added annotation when the user pans or zooms the map and annotations come onto the screen again.  Generally, always use the `annotation` parameter as the basis for any logic in the delegate method.